# Is it possible to define a new entity type with attributes in Dynamics CRM through API?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We have a asp.net webapplication. In this we allow our user to define his own types and collect information about users based on the types he created. Some of our users also use Microsoft Dynamics CRM. We want to integrate these collected information into Dynamics CRM. I have no idea how could we runtime create new entity types with attributes that the user defined in our system.

Or if you have a better idea, please share it. I went through the related videos in the CRM 2011 training kit, but found nothing useful.

Comment: as far as I know, it's not possible to create new entities on the fly through the crm SDK. You'd also have to somehow regenerate the CRM model with crmsvcutil every time a new entity was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509014.aspx)

Looks like CreateEntityRequest and CreateAttributeRequest are main points of interest for you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use the metadata service to do this.
More information available here:
http://raotayyabali.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/ms-dynamics-crm-2011-metadatacreate-new-entity/